# How to have Zsh completion menu and use glob patterns + recursive search?

Tags: bash, zsh, autocomplete

I have the following setup for zsh completion

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zstyle ':completion:*' complete-options true

setopt GLOB_COMPLETE
zstyle ':completion*:default' menu 'select=0'
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
zmodload zsh/complist
```

Which gives me a nice autocomplete menu when I tab, where I can switch between different options. However, I'd like to be able to do `./**/*file*<tab>` and get a selectable list of all options available.

I notice that if I remove all the previous options that I have enabled, `./**/*file*<tab>` works but it expands to all available options. I'd like to have it instead as a menu of options that I can tab between. However, if I enable the completion list, `./**/*file*<tab>` stops working and doesn't do anything.

So how do I enable so that I can recursively search for a file and have it show up in an auto-completion menu that I can tab between?